# При парсинге сайта не могу достать скрытый html

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, bs4

[image: скрин body сайта]

```
link = https://doq.kz/doctor/li-mariya
req = requests.get(link, headers=header)        
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

При <kbd>Сtrl+Shift+C</kbd> и нажатии на любой фрагмент html код виден, но soup мне показывает только то, что в скрытом скрипте. Посмотрел аналогичную проблему у кого то в stackoverflow, но не смог ничего реализовать...

Comment: Если вы в браузере просмотрите Исходный код страницы, то увидите ровным счетом то же самое, что на скрине. Контент страницы подтягивается аяксом. Откройте панель разработчика, вкладку Сеть - xhr, просмотрите какие запросы отправляются и какие данные приходят. Среди них найдете и нужный вам контент. это впридачу упростит вам парсинг.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Адрес api, который возвращает данные: `api.doq.kz/api/v0/doctor`:

```
import requests


url = 'https://api.doq.kz/api/v0/doctors/li-mariya/'
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36'
}


r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = r.json()
```

В `data` - словарь с данными:

```
print(f"{data['first_name']} {data['patronymic_name']} {data['last_name']})
```

выведет:

```
Мария Бонсиковна Ли
```

Полный ответ в data:

```
{'id': 2901, 'is_valid': True, 'pretty_url': 'li-mariya', 'first_name': 'Мария', 'last_name': 'Ли', 'patronymic_name': 'Бонсиковна', 'avatar_abs_url': 'https://doq.kz/media/doctors/118665372_315299009895796_6101684596666964237_n.jpg', 'experience': 37, 'science_degree': None, 'academic_status': None, 'avg_grade': 0.0, 'feedback_count': 0, 'clinic_branches': [{'id': 403, 'clinic_id': 294, 'clinic_pretty_url': 'dostarmed-almaty', 'name': 'Достар Мед', 'city': {'id': 3, 'name': 'Алматы', 'pretty_url': 'almaty', 'lng': 76.945465, 'lat': 43.238293}, 'address': 'ул. Байкадамова, 5', 'yclients_company_id': None, 'specialties': [{'id': 35, 'cbhd_id': 5654, 'name': 'Терапевт', 'doctor_category': None, 'price': 7000, 'discount': 0, 'discount_is_percent': True, 'total': 7000, 'yclients_staff_id': None, 'subspecialties': [], 'doctor_type': {'0': 'Взрослый'}, 'premium': False, 'is_house_call': False, 'is_online': False, 'is_for_children': False, 'prices': {'price': 7000, 'total': 7000, 'discount': 0, 'price_for_children': 7000, 'price_for_children_discount': 0, 'price_for_children_total': 7000, 'online_price': None, 'online_price_discount': 0, 'online_price_total': None, 'house_call_price': None, 'house_call_price_discount': 0, 'house_call_price_total': None}, 'children_age_from': 0, 'children_age_to': 216}], 'services': [], 'is_open': True, 'appointment_fields': [{'id': 1, 'title': 'ИИН пациента', 'type': {'2': 'String'}, 'is_required': True, 'max_length': 12, 'min_length': 12}, {'id': 3, 'title': 'Фамилия пациента', 'type': {'2': 'String'}, 'is_required': False, 'max_length': None, 'min_length': None}], 'clinic': {'id': 294, 'name': 'Достар Мед', 'pretty_url': 'dostarmed-almaty', 'avatar_abs_url': 'https://api.doq.kz/media/clinics/ab5072cda8b86bffbfdda6bc33934285.jpg'}, 'lng': 76.9016558, 'lat': 43.2144959, 'distance': '', 'schedule': {'id': 2420, 'items': [{'schedule_type': 0, 'day_of_the_week': 0, 'around_the_clock': False, 'start_time': '9:00', 'end_time': '21:00'}, {'schedule_type': 0, 'day_of_the_week': 1, 'around_the_clock': False, 'start_time': '9:00', 'end_time': '21:00'}, {'schedule_type': 0, 'day_of_the_week': 2, 'around_the_clock': False, 'start_time': '9:00', 'end_time': '21:00'}, {'schedule_type': 0, 'day_of_the_week': 3, 'around_the_clock': False, 'start_time': '9:00', 'end_time': '21:00'}, {'schedule_type': 0, 'day_of_the_week': 4, 'around_the_clock': False, 'start_time': '9:00', 'end_time': '21:00'}, {'schedule_type': 0, 'day_of_the_week': 5, 'around_the_clock': False, 'start_time': '9:00', 'end_time': '21:00'}, {'schedule_type': 0, 'day_of_the_week': 6, 'around_the_clock': False, 'start_time': '9:00', 'end_time': '21:00'}]}, 'online_schedule': True, 'direct_call_phone': '+77008366815'}], 'meta_title': 'Ли Мария Бонсиковна - терапевт: 0 отзывов, запись онлайн - DOQ.kz', 'meta_description': 'Запишитесь онлайн к Ли Мария Бонсиковна - врач терапевт в Алматы. Отзывы. Биография. Принимает в клинике Достар Мед', 'title_desktop': 'Ли Мария Бонсиковна', 'title_mobile': 'Ли Мария Бонсиковна'}
```

Comment: мне это помогло, я незнаю как отметить твой коммент как решение или проголосовать так как я новенький, и мне говорит что у меня мало голосов для голосования

Comment: @ThemForest, Просто нажми на принять ответ.